# openam rest api json/users/?_fields=ismemberof attribute does not show updated result

Tags: openam

Using openam 12.0.0.0 Found One issue with openam with retrieving groups information of current login using api

```
      "/json/users/username/?_fields=ismemberof"
```

scenario:

I had tried with  this rest api by adding User attribute” ismemberof” from openam console.

after than I had retrieve groups information for current login user using restapi "/json/users/username/?_fields=ismemberof"

which return me this:

```
curl --header"iPlanetDirectoryPro:AQIC5wM2LY4SfczExeheltxgjSN7wrCR5XhfEGF5kj6t6C4.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtMzQ0NzM3MDc3MzE1MjMwNjEwOQ..*" http://openam.server:8080/openam/json/users/indrani?_fields=ismemberof
```

output:

```
   {"ismemberof":["cn=grp1,ou=groups,o=openam","cn=grp2,ou=groups,o=openam"]}
```

After some time I had  remove my user from grp1 and save from openam console
ie, now current user only have one group ie grp2

Again using  curl command for getting list of groups for current user:

```
 curl --header"iPlanetDirectoryPro:AQIC5wM2LY4SfczExeheltxgjSN7wrCR5XhfEGF5kj6t6C4.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtMzQ0NzM3MDc3MzE1MjMwNjEwOQ..*" http://openam.server:8080/openam/json/users/indrani?_fields=ismemberof
```

output:

```
{"ismemberof":["cn=grp1,ou=groups,o=openam","cn=grp2,ou=groups,o=openam"]}
```

the issue is it gving same response  with two groups, 
even Current user only have one group. ie it give old response

This issue is solve if I restart the openam server I will get expected result.

```
     {"ismemberof":["cn=grp2,ou=groups,o=openam"]}
```

It should not take to restart openam server , to get original response.

When I connect to my LDAP data store using active directory studio, i can see values updated against the user for ismemberof which is an virtual attribute but when I hit curl response is old cached one only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on the settings and data store used OpenAM caches attributes of user identities. The cache is kept in synch with the real LDAP server by either using persistent search - or notification change control (AD).

If your LDAP server does not support persistent search control or you did not allow notification change control the cache can not be dirtied hence OpenAM will return the outdated value for the identity attribute 'isMemberOf'

Comment: Thanks Bernhard for reply.This means there is issue with openam ladp server, .... We had also checked with openam developers about this issue, but they replied back, there they replied there is limitation of openam rest api, rerfer this : https://forgerock.org/topic/cannot-read-user-belongs-to-which-group/#post-3083. Is there any  other way to get list of groups details of particular user belongs.

Comment: I agree , current openAM 12.0.0 have issues with their cache for updating user entry on group membership.Entry is only updated against the group, but user entry on group changes remains intact. On openAM restart the changes are seen. I can see changes getting reflected in openDJ DB but not on openAM side, means openDJ does not get notified on changes on vitrual attributes i.e. ismemberof

Comment: This is how OpenAM IdRepo API works , it has nothing to to with REST API in particular. REST API just leverages IdRepo API. By default a caching implementation is used which caches the attributes. Just make sure that the notification mode (persistent search or notification change control) works as expected ... or don't use the caching implementation

Comment: reading the group membership from the entry is NOT LDAP compliant ... AD needs it and OpenDJ offers it as a feature